# Laravel hasManyThrough a polymorphic relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I have a table with transactions where every `Transaction` belongs to either a `Driver`, or a `Customer` - so I set a polymorphic relation between them.

For Transaction I have set:

```
public function owner() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

For Driver and Customer:

```
public function transactions() {
    return $this->morphMany(Transaction::class, 'owner');
}
```

But each driver also belongs to a `Company`. And I am trying to get all transactions that belong to a `Company` through `hasManyThrough` relation:

```
public function transactions() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Transaction::class, Driver::class);
}
```

But it seems to not work on a polymorphic relations, as it throws an error because it tries to look for a `driver_id` field at `transactions` table.

What is the way to get all the transactions that belong to a Company through its drivers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specify the custom foreign key and add a constraint for the `owner_type` column:

```php
public function transactions() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Transaction::class, Driver::class, null, 'owner_id')
        ->where('owner_type', Driver::class);
}
```

Without the constraint, you would get transactions of different owners that have the same `id`.

Comment: That works, thanks! And also answers my question about getting transactions of other owners with the same `id`. Only one question left: what does `null` stand for? I seem to have tried quite the same, but like `
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Transaction::class, Driver::class, null, 'owner_id')`.

Comment: The third argument is the foreign key in the `drivers` table. When you pass `null`, Laravel uses the default `company_id`. You can also pass the value explicitly.